# Why does this async generator cause the JavaScript runtime to hang?

Tags: javascript

The following JavaScript causes the runtime to hang on Chrome (v80.0.3987.116) and Firefox (v72.0.2) on OSX 10.15.2.

Why?

Note that I am marking the iterator function as `async`.

```js
const iterable = {
    async *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield 'one'
    }
}

console.log([...iterable])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because now your `[Symbol.iterator]` method no longer returns an Iterator, it does return an AsyncIterator. That's still an object with a `.next()` method, so the spread syntax trying to iterate it doesn't complain. But the calls to the `.next()` method do no longer return `{value:…, done:true}` objects, they always return a promise. These promise objects have no truthy `done` property, so your iterator never stops…

You can achieve the same result with

```
const iterable = {
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        while (true) {
            yield
        }
    }
}    
console.log([...iterable])
```

or

```
const iterable = {
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        return {
            next() {
                return {};
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log([...iterable])
```

Answer (score 3):

When you call `console.log([...iterable])`, it tells Javascript to get a generator from `Symbol.iterator` property on `iterable` to iterate over it. Where, `Symbol.iterator` is `AsyncGenerator`(because of `async` in front of it), rather not a regular `Generator`. Meaning that `next` function from that generator returns a `Promise`, but not an object with `done` and `value` values. So, js takes that returned `Promise` and looks for `done` property to be `true` to stop iteration, but returned `Promise` doesn't have this property, so the check fails and js keeps the iterations going.

The same result can be achieved in this way:

```js
const iterable = {
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return {
      next() {
        return {} // <~ doesn't have done property - will cause infinite iteration
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log([...iterable])
```

Hope it helps <3